# Automating Split, Save Name and Error Checking with Acrobat Action Scripts?

Tags: pdf, automation, acrobat

I'm considering convincing my company to upgrade to Acrobat Pro so I can automate the processing of my scanned documents. Before I bring it up, I want to make sure the things I want to do are possible. I don't need anyone to give me the code, I just want to know if this is possible.

The documents i'm working with are landscape, 2-5 pages, and have the filename and page numbers in the footer. I want to scan a big stack of them and have a script perform the following actions:

1. Use OCR to acquire the filename and page numbers for each page. I would like to restrict the OCR to only look at the footer to save time and RAM.
2. Using the filenames, I want it to detect when one document ends and the next one begins so they can be split into separate files.
3. Before saving the split files, check that the number of pages in the file matches the page total in the footer. (I work in a factory and the documents can get sticky, so my scanner frequently pulls two pages at once)
4. Instead of saving the files where the page total doesn't match, compile a list of the errors so I know which documents need to be rescanned.
5. Finally, save all correct documents with their filenames from the footer to a folder on my desktop.

This could save me hours a week, so I'm hopeful that it's all possible. Thanks

Comment: It's not going to be trivial but it **is** possible. The hiccup is going to be when the footer file names are identical but the OCR fails to read them properly and sees them as different. You'd be able to test that against the page number but, again, not trivial.

Comment: @joelgeraci I think I can figure out a work around for that. Someone on the Adobe Support forum told me that OCR can't be limited to the footer, do you know if this is true?

Comment: It's true, you also can't limit the text extraction to the footer either but you can decide to process only words that occur within a certain bounding box. But as I stated, it's not trivial and is a lot longer than what an answer would allow.